# Relacionamento muitos para muitos ASP.NET Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, mvc, relacionamento

Estou com dificuldades para fazer o relacionamento entre minhas tabelas utilizando o EF.

Na hora de criar uma OrdemDeManutencao, preciso listar os dados registrados em outras tabelas, como Equipamentos, Tarefas e Pessoa, como tento representar na classe abaixo:

```
public class OrdemDeManutencao
{
    [Key]
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Código")]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    //como fazer relacionamento muitos para muitos??
    public List<Equipamentos> Equipamentos { get; set; }
    public List<Tarefas> Tarefas { get; set; }
    public List<Pessoa> Tecnicos { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Data de Abertura")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime DataAbertura { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Data Realizado")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime DataRealizado { get; set; }

    public StatusOrdem Status { get; set; }

    public PrioridadeOrdem Prioridade { get; set; }
}
```

Como consigo listar os registros feitos em Equipamentos, Tarefas e Pessoa, na OrdemDeManutencao?

Agradeço desde já!

Answer (score 2):

Se for de N-N você terá que criar antes de tudo tabelas intermediarias para cada entidade, a fim de não interferir na estrutura da tabela.

Caso seja de 1-N entre

OrdemManutencao-Equipamentos
OrdemManutencao-Tarefas
OrdemManutencao-Tecnicos

Usando **Fluent Api**

```
HasRequired(hr => hr.OrdemDeManutencao)
    .WithMany(wm => wm.Equipamentos)
    .HasForeignKey(fk => fk.OrdemDeManutencaoFK);

HasRequired(hr => hr.OrdemDeManutencao)
    .WithMany(wm => wm.Tarefas)
    .HasForeignKey(fk => fk.OrdemDeManutencaoFK);

HasRequired(hr => hr.OrdemDeManutencao)
    .WithMany(wm => wm.Pessoas)
    .HasForeignKey(fk => fk.OrdemDeManutencaoFK);

public class Equipamentos
{

    public virtual OrdemDeManutencaoFK { get; set; }

    public virtual OrdemDeManutencao OrdemDeManutencao { get; set; }

}

public class Tarefas
{

    public virtual OrdemDeManutencaoFK { get; set; }

    public virtual OrdemDeManutencao OrdemDeManutencao { get; set; }

}

public class Tecnicos
{

    public virtual int OrdemDeManutencaoFK { get; set; }

    public virtual OrdemDeManutencao OrdemDeManutencao { get; set; }

}
```

Usando **DataAnnotations**

```
public class Equipamentos
{
    public virtual OrdemDeManutencaoFK { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("OrdemDeManutencaoFK")]
    public virtual OrdemDeManutencao OrdemDeManutencao { get; set; }
}

public class Tarefas
{

    public virtual OrdemDeManutencaoFK { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("OrdemDeManutencaoFK")]
    public virtual OrdemDeManutencao OrdemDeManutencao { get; set; }
}

public class Tecnicos
{
    public virtual int OrdemDeManutencaoFK { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("OrdemDeManutencaoFK")]
    public virtual OrdemDeManutencao OrdemDeManutencao { get; set; }
}
```

PS: Não esqueça de deixar como **virtual** e quando se tratar de listas, deixe como o tipo **ICollection**. A questão do virtual é a nomenclatura pro Entity Framework poder validar quando se é lazy loading (se desejar utilizar) e o ICollection é porque já tive problemas com isso e ele não puxava o lazy loading.

```
public class OrdemDeManutencao
{
    [Key]
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Código")]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    //como fazer relacionamento muitos para muitos??
    public virtual ICollection<Equipamentos> Equipamentos { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Tarefas> Tarefas { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Pessoa> Tecnicos { get; set; }

    // resto da classe
}
```